# GUI Testing tools forBusiness analaysts

Tags: testing

I have been looking around stackoverflow for automated GUI tools for testing our web app gui from a Business analyst point of view, so that means strictly requirements-record-playback kind of testing  since we are not really programmers.
We have used selenium in the past but unfortunately it is no longer compatible with Firefox 4.

Is there a similar tool to selenium that allows recording and playback of GUI tests that does not require a lot or any scripting on a windows platform? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FireFox add on compatibility reporter to get Selenium working on FF4

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/

Or alternatively drop down to FireFox 3.x and use that just for your testing!

Answer (score 0):

For the server component  Selenium-RC (necessary to execute tests), You must run Selenium-RC 2.0b3 (or higher if it become) to be compatible with Firefox 4. I have used it succesfully with FF4.

Selenium IDE, the  recording tool, for firefox is indeed not available as a plugin for FF4 (but I speculate it will be coming soon).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can benefit from AutoIt (http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) I`d been using it to test Windows based GUI, but to the best of knowledge there are lot of scripts to test/play on-line games, thus it is applicable to Web Sites.

It does not require deep technical knowledge, but of course it will be much better and frequently mandatory to optimize the generated code. I`ve started my experience with this tool, and I was doing my work flawlessly.

At one company, I was developing automated tests for web app by means of TestPartner (Compuware company) it was one of the best tools I`ve ever worked with, it generates VB code quite 'intelligently' and supports user with administration features. But I`m not sure whether it is possible to use it without paying.

Good luck !